# Local storage not working on iPad browser private window

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, ipad

I have developed hybrid app through REACT js. It's working fine on desktop and as a app. But it's not working on device (Ipad or mobile phones) any browser private windows. The problem is, I can't get or set `localStorage` value in private window at device only. How can I get `LocalStorage` value?

Answer (score 3):

Localstorage is disabled in private mode on ios. Even in the normal mode localstorage can be wiped "randomly".

Here the passage on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
    Note: Starting with iOS 5.1, Safari Mobile stores localStorage data in 
    the cache folder, which is subject to occasional clean up, at the behest 
    of the OS, typically if space is short. Safari Mobile's Private Browsing 
    mode also prevents writing to localStorage entirely.
```

Comment: so there is no possible to get local storage in iOS device ?

Comment: Well you could just not use localstorage. I don't know what usecase you need your storage for. So I cant recommend any alternatives right now. But there are other ways to store userdata.

Comment: yes i want store user data locally ...what are the other way

Comment: There aren't that many ways i guess. Cookies would be working. There is also is the **deprecated** webSql. Which still works in safari.